# Orchestrate recursive quicksort calls via WaitGroup

Tags: recursion, go, concurrency, synchronization, quicksort

I am trying to run recursive quicksort calls in parallel:

```
func quicksort(a []int) {
    quicksortRecursive(a)
    wg.Wait()
    insertionsort(a)
}

func quicksortRecursive(a []int) {
    if len(a) > THRESHOLD {
        l, r := partition(a)
        wg.Add(2)
        go func() {
            quicksortRecursive(a[:r+1])
            wg.Done()
        }()
        go func() {
            go quicksortRecursive(a[l:])
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
}
```

The `go` calls appear overly clunky to me. Is the following, more readable version still correct?

```
func quicksort(a []int) {
    wg.Add(1)
    quicksortRecursive(a)
    wg.Wait()
    insertionsort(a)
}

func quicksortRecursive(a []int) {
    if len(a) > THRESHOLD {
        l, r := partition(a)
        wg.Add(2)
        go quicksortRecursive(a[:r+1])
        go quicksortRecursive(a[l:])
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

I am specifically wondering whether calling the initial `wg.Add(1)` and the corresponding `wg.Done()` in the same thread is kosher.

Comment: at first look I can tell you that solution has a notable overhead creating *N* goroutines, which aren't parallel, _concurrency is not parallelism_

Answer (score 2):

If it works correctly, then it's correct. In terms of code quality, I don't see anything wrong with the approach, other than a slight concern about the use of a global variable for the `WaitGroup`. If it's a small app it's probably fine, otherwise I would use a local variable created in `quicksort` and passed as a parameter to `quicksortRecursive`.